# Let $G$ a group with normal subgroups $M,N$ such that $M\cap N=\{e\}$. Show that if $G$ is generated by $M\cup N$ then $G\cong M \times N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ a group with normal subgroups $M,N$ such that $M\cap N=\{e\}$.
>   i) Show that for every $m\in M$ and for every $n\in N$, $mn=nm$.
>   ii) If $G$ is generated by $M\cup N$ then $G\cong M \times N$.

This is an homework question for abstract algebra. I think I can prove $i)$. But I have no idea how to prove $ii)$. Can anybody give me a hint for this one ?

---

Here my proof for i): Let $n \in N$ and let $m\in M$. Let $x=mnm^{-1}n^{-1}$. As $N$ is normal subgroup, $mnm^{-1} \in N$. Therefore $x \in N$. 
As $M$ is normal subgroup , $nmn^{-1} \in M$. Since $m\in M$, then $x=m(nm^{-1}n^{-1})\in M$. This implies that $c\in M \cap N$, then $c\in \{e\}$, then $c=e$, and we get $mn=nm$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Show that $$MN=\{mn:m\in M,n\in N\}=G.$$ (Suffices to show that $M\cup N\subseteq MN$.) Now show that the map $$mn\mapsto (m,n)$$ is a well-defined isomorphism $MN\to M\times N$. Part (i) will come in handy here.

Comment: Thank you for this hint! Is this correct ?
\begin{align*}
f(m_1n_1m_2n_2) &= f(m_1m_2n_1n_2) &&(i)\\ 
 &=(m_1m_2,n_1n_2) \\ 
 &=(m_1,n_1)(n_1,n_2) \\ 
 &=f(m_1n_1)f(m_2n_2)  
\end{align*}

Therefore $f$ homomorphism. $f$ is wel defined as if $m_1n_1=m_2n_2$, then $m_1=m_2$ and $n_1=n_2$ as $(M\cap N =\{e\}$. So $(m_1,n_1)=(m_2,n_2)$. The inverse is also well defined as if $(m_1,n_1)=(m_2,n_2)$. Then $m_1=m_2$ and $n_1=n_2$. And therefore $m_1n_1=m_2n_2$. Therefore $f$ is an well-defined isomorphism.

Comment: Well done. That's the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your proof looks fine, but as for (ii): isn't that *exactly* the  very definition of direct product of groups? I mean, we have

$$1)\;\;\;\;G=MN\;,\;\;\text{since we have that}\;\;\forall\,g\in\exists\,x_i\in M\cup N\;\;s.t.\;\;g=\prod_{i}x_i\in MN$$

$$2)\;\;\;\;M,N\lhd G$$

$$3)\;\;\;\;M\cap N=\{1\}$$

Unless you have *other* definition, the above is exactly the definition of (inner) direct product of subgroups of a group $\,G\,$